# Utilising Left Outer Join correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

Table one has a list of contacts
Table 2 has a list of distribution lists
Table 3 has a list of contacts associated with each of the distribution lists.

I am trying to get a list of all Contacts under a particular scheme and include any distribution lists they are in, and still return the contact if they are not in any distribution list.

so

Table 1 : Contacts

| ID | Firstname | Surname | ServiceID--- | Email------- | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | Blogs | 1136 | jb@email.com | xxxxx |
| 2 | Sue | Bloggs | 1136 | sb@email.com | xxxxx |
| 3 | Jamie | Howard | 1146 | Xxxxx | xxxxx |
| 4 | Joseph | Stalin | 1146 | Xxxxx | xxxxx |
| 5 | Helen | Blower | 1136 | Xxxxx | xxxxx |
| 6 | Mike | Grys | 1136 | Xxxxx | xxxxx |
| 7 | Rose | Flower | 1146 | Xxxxx | xxxxx |
| 8 | John | Prior | 1136 |  | xxxxx |

Table 2: Distribution lists

| Distlistid | distlistname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Red Zone |
| 2 | Blue Zone |
| 3 | Yellow Zone |
| 4 | Pink Zone |
| 5 | Green Zone |

Table 3 : Distribution list Contacts

| Distlistid | Contact id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |

Script I am using is:

```sql
SELECT c.firstName,
       c.lastName,
       c.comments,
       dl.distListName,
       dl.description
FROM app.Contact c WITH (NOLOCK)
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN app.DistListContacts DC ON c.id = DC.contactID
     JOIN app.DistList dl ON DC.distListID = dl.id
WHERE c.serviceID = 1136
GROUP BY dl.distListName,
         c.firstName,
         c.lastName,
         c.comments,
         dl.description
ORDER BY c.lastName,
         c.firstName;
```

So I want a list of all contacts under serviceid 1136 and what distribution list they are a member of if any.

I have tried left outer join but I only seem to get the contacts that have a distribution list, not the ones that dont.

Probably a very simple mistake I am making?

Comment: HTML markup for data isn't very helpful. Post the data as DDL and DML statements, well formatted tabular `text`, or in a markdown table.

Comment: Hi, can you show us the code you tried ?

Comment: Images of data is even worse. Don't expect the users here to transcribe your image, they won't. *"Post the data as DDL and DML statements, well formatted tabular `text`, or in a markdown table."*

Comment: Most likely you are trying to filter left-joined tables in where clause. If so, move criteria to on clause.

Comment: I have also tried removing the group by as they arent needed

Comment: All the joins have to be LEFT JOIN in this case.

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` at all? You have no aggregation here. You have a `RIGHT JOIN` to `app.DistListContacts`, which would be like having a `LEFT JOIN` to `app.Contact` however, you also have `c.serviceID = 1136` in your `WHERE`, this means that *all* your joins are effectively `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: Thank you I had already swapped the right join back as it was only made right when I was playing, however adding teh second join as a Left join made this work. Perfectly thank you very much

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: You need LEFT JOIN not RIGHT JOIN

Comment: Where is the column comments ? In your query you have it and in your table you do not. Also, there are some naming confusion here - for example in your table examples you give us column "Surname" and in your query it is lastName ? Please help us help you and correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN`
Here is a simple query that will give you your desired results. I have removed columns "description" and "comments" because I do not know where did you got them from.

```
select c.firstName,
       c.lastName,
       dl.distListName,
       c.serviceID
from Contact c
left JOIN DistListContacts DC ON c.id = DC.contactID
left JOIN DistList dl ON DC.distListID = dl.id
WHERE c.serviceID = 1136
ORDER BY c.lastName,
         c.firstName;
```

Here you can see the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d95418458a74aa4f6e603c68a4773227)